# Failing to update self credential of an app using azure graph API (REST and JAVA)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to insert credential to an already present active directory application using the Azure graph api for java.

I have initialized the request using the same application credential (Of MyRegisteredApp).

`ActiveDirectoryApplication application = graphRbacManager.applications().getByName("MyRegisteredApp");
    application.update().definePasswordCredential("passwd").withPasswordValue("mypassword")
        .withDuration(Duration.standardDays(700)).attach().apply();`

However I am getting 403 error

`com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.GraphErrorException: Status code 403, {"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.microsoft.rest.ServiceResponseBuilder.build(ServiceResponseBuilder.java:122)
    at com.microsoft.azure.AzureResponseBuilder.build(AzureResponseBuilder.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner.patchDelegate(ApplicationsInner.java:650)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner.access$400(ApplicationsInner.java:45)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner$22.call(ApplicationsInner.java:637)
    at com.microsoft.azure.management.graphrbac.implementation.ApplicationsInner$22.call(ApplicationsInner.java:633)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.deliverResponse(CallArbiter.java:120)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallArbiter.emitResponse(CallArbiter.java:102)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:46)
    at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.CallExecuteOnSubscribe.call(CallExecuteOnSubscribe.java:24)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap.call(OnSubscribeMap.java:33)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.call(OperatorSubscribeOn.java:100)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$EventLoopWorker$1.call(CachedThreadScheduler.java:230)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

I have global admin access and the MyRegisteredApp application has all the access rights.
What am I doing wrong?

[image: MyRegisteredApp Access]

Answer (score 1):

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Based on the error details and screenshot you provided, the permissions have been selected. However, you can't save the grant step otherwise the permission would not be effective.

[image]

Comment: This is also done, but still the error remains the same.

Comment: Does an app registration have ability to update its own password credential?